# Can self referencing table pivot to show family lineage for every child with generation count giving rise to the names of each column?

Tags: sql-server, recursion, pivot, parent-child, common-table-expression

I have a self-referencing table of parents and children and I have written a recursive CTE so I now have a list of parent-child relationships with their depths against them i.e. which generation they are in.
Is it now possible to pivot this to show great-grandparents' Ids in the left column, then grandparents in the next column, then parents, then children etc. with their respective generations as the column headings please?

e.g. with the data you see I'm inserting into my temp table, can I get this please?

```
Gen0    Gen1        Gen2        Gen3        Gen4
1       2           3           4           5
10      20          100         1000
10      20          200     
10      30
10      40
```

```
create table [#Data] ([ParentId] int, [ChildId] int)
insert [#Data] values
    (1, 2)
    , (2, 3)
    , (3, 4)
    , (4, 5 )
    , (10, 20)
    , (10, 30)
    , (10, 40)
    , (20, 100)
    , (20, 200)
    , (200, 1000)

;with [CTE] AS
    (
    select [A].[ParentId], [A].[ChildId], 1 as [Generation]
    from [#Data] [A]
    left join [#Data] [B]
        on [A].[ParentId] = [B].[ChildId]
    where [B].[ChildId] is null
    union all
    select [D].[ParentId], [D].[ChildId], [Generation] + 1
    from [CTE] [C]
    join [#Data] [D]
        on [C].[ChildId] = [D].[ParentId]
    )
    select * from [CTE] order by [ParentId], [ChildId]
```

I am using SQL 2017.
Many thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this to query your CTE:

```
;with [CTE] AS
(/*your code here*/)
select 
      g1.[ParentId]                         as Gen0
   ,  coalesce(g1.[ChildId], g2.[ParentId]) as Gen1
   ,  coalesce(g2.[ChildId], g3.[ParentId]) as Gen2
   ,  coalesce(g3.[ChildId], g4.[ParentId]) as Gen3
   ,  g4.[ChildId]                          as Gen4
from 
    [CTE] as g1
    left join [CTE] as g2 on g1.[ChildId] = g2.[ParentId]
    left join [CTE] as g3 on g2.[ChildId] = g3.[ParentId]
    left join [CTE] as g4 on g3.[ChildId] = g4.[ParentId]

where g1.[Generation] = 1
```

Result:

[image]

See the complete code [here](https://rextester.com/GQBG87904). This is a static solution, if you want something that works with an arbitrary number of generations, you'll have to transform this code in dynamic TSQL.

P.S. I think there is probably a typo in your expected results: in Gen3 column 1000 should be on the third row, not on the second since 1000 is child of 200, not of 100